# Problem with creating glass texture

Tags: texturing, glass

I keep trying to create a glass texture by following every youtube tutorial I can find. They all say just turn the transmission up to 1 and turn the roughness all the way down on a principle bsdf node. But every time I do exactly that my surface just turns solid black. I think it's because I have version 2.93.1 and everyone on youtube uses 2.8.

I noticed that when I DON'T turn roughness all the way down, the texture appears to be like glass. However, I don't mean to be picky, but I'm not happy with it. I want more of a plexiglass look. I'm hoping someone can give me some tips on the look I'm going for and also explain why my objects look black.[image]

Comment: Scroll down in your material settings until you find **Blend Mode**. Change it away from _opaque_ (alpha-blend works well). You may or may not need to toggle "backface culling" and/or "show backface". Also, you are currently in material preview mode (default for shading tab) - press z in the 3d viewport and select "rendered" from the pie menu to see your object with your own scene lighting.

Comment: Your left HDRI preview sphere is pitch black. That's a bug. Do you have an Intel HD graphics unit? There is a bug in Blender 2.93 that causes any material to become black when *Roughness* is less than *0.0038...* => [T88754 - Intel HD graphics: Changing Roughness Value to 0 causes mesh to be black](https://developer.blender.org/T88754)

Comment: Wow both of your comments are very informative. Thanks a lot!